# Is Intelligence useless for Clerics in Disgaea: Hour of Darkness?

Tags: disgaea

I have heard that Intelligence increases spell power and that Resistance increases the power of healing spells. However when I first read this I was confused if that meant the resistence of the castor or castee. I also believed that both intelligence and resistence increased the power of healing spells.

[The most specific statement I've found regarding this is](http://disgaea.wikia.com/wiki/Statistics):

> Intelligence - Increases magical attack power and accuracy. [...]
>   Resistance - Gives 70% of magical defences, and boosts the amount of
>   health healed from a healing spell. Also boosts the 4 stat boosting
>   spells.(Shield-Defence; Braveheart-Attack; Magic Boost-Intelligence;
>   Magic Wall-Resistance)

However, initially Clerics have a higher INT stat that RES! The above quote seems to mean that intelligence is useless for clerics unless you plan to give them combat spells. **Is it useless for Clerics?**

Bonus: Anyone know exactly what the healing spell formula is?

Comment: Are you referring to a specific game in the series (E.g. Disgaea 4) or are just the game mechanics in general? I believe Disgaea 1 uses INT for healing, but from Phantom Brave onward, RES affects healing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not entirely correct.

In the [original Disgaea](http://strategywiki.org/wiki/Disgaea:_Hour_of_Darkness/Stats), INT is still the determining factor for the healing amount.  In all subsequent Disgaea games, it was switched over to RES.  In the first, I believe the RES of the recipient also plays a factor into how much they are healed, but the int of the caster is the biggest factor.

Also, there is no reason for your cleric to be a dual mode (in fact, they become more handy if you learn the boost spells from a mage as well as some damage spells).  Just have the cleric make a few students and learn the spells from them by standing next to the students (which gives them access to the spell).

Comment: The page you linked to was the original page which confused me as it says RES plays a role in how much healing is done. I understand how to teach a cleric offensive spells. What do you mean by dual mode? Wonder if it's better to teach a mage healing spells or a cleric mage spells? You've answered my original question so will mark as accepted in the morning :)

Comment: @Annan by dual mode I did mean teach a cleric all the spells, including mage spells.  As for deciding between a mage or a cleric, a galaxy mage has a higher int aptitude so it'll benefit more from int boosting items.

Comment: Is this still true for Afteroon of Darkness?

Comment: @Ben I don't know about that one